# Use WEKA API to perform LSA on train and test set

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, weka, document-classification, text-classification

I need to use Weka and its AttributeSelection algorithm LatentSemanticAnalysis to do text classification. I have my dataset split into training and test sets on which I want to apply LSA. I have read some posts regarding LSA, however I have not found how I can use it on to seperate datasets and keep them compatible. This is what I have so far but runs out of memory...:

```
AttributeSelection selecter = new AttributeSelection();
weka.attributeSelection.LatentSemanticAnalysis lsa = new weka.attributeSelection.LatentSemanticAnalysis();
Ranker rank = new Ranker();

selecter.setEvaluator(lsa);
selecter.setSearch(rank);
selecter.setRanking(true);

selecter.SelectAttributes(input);
Instances outputData = selecter.reduceDimensionality(input);
```

**Edit1**
In responce to @Jose's reply I added a new version of my source code. This leads to an OutOfMemoryError:

```
AttributeSelection filter = new AttributeSelection(); // package weka.filters.supervised.attribute!
LatentSemanticAnalysis lsa = new LatentSemanticAnalysis();
Ranker rank = new Ranker();
filter.setEvaluator(lsa);
filter.setSearch(rank);
filter.setInputFormat(train);

train = Filter.useFilter(train, filter);
test = Filter.useFilter(test, filter);
```

**Edit2**
The error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at weka.core.matrix.Matrix.getArrayCopy(Matrix.java:301)
at weka.core.matrix.SingularValueDecomposition.<init>(SingularValueDecomposition.java:76)
at weka.core.matrix.Matrix.svd(Matrix.java:913)
at weka.attributeSelection.LatentSemanticAnalysis.buildAttributeConstructor(LatentSemanticAnalysis.java:511)
at weka.attributeSelection.LatentSemanticAnalysis.buildEvaluator(LatentSemanticAnalysis.java:416)
at weka.attributeSelection.AttributeSelection.SelectAttributes(AttributeSelection.java:596)
at weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection.batchFinished(AttributeSelection.java:455)
at weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(Filter.java:682)
at test.main(test.java:44)
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the heap memory allocated to your java program through the [-Xmx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java) command line argument to the java executable?

Comment: @StevenMagana-Zook yes, it's already at 2048MB

Comment: @StevenMagana-Zook I cranked it up to 4096MB and still OutOfMemoryError

Comment: How big is your data set, and how much RAM is on your computer? From your stack trace it seems that copying the svd matrix pushes you over your limit.

Comment: @StevenMagana-Zook I have 118 class attributes and 25,765 attributes used in 9,603 instances. This is for the trainset, for the test set I have same number of class and normal attributes but here I have 3,299 instances. If it would help resolve my issue, I am using the Reuters21578 (ModApte split) dataset. In total I have 8GB of RAM on my 2011 MBP intel core 2duo

Comment: my eclipse is taking default -xmx only even though I changed the value in the argument. can you tell whats the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As `AttributeSelection` is a filter, you can apply it in batch mode (`-b` option) to a training & a test subset at once, thus representing the test dataset according to the dimensions defined in the training set.

You can check how to do this in a program at [Use Weka in your Java code - Filter - Batch filtering](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code#Filter-Batch%20filtering).

Comment: Thank you, I have something running however I end up with an OutOfMemoryError. I have added piece of code which is used for the transformation with LSA.

Comment: Is there any possibility you could help me out sir? I would appreciate it so much!

Comment: hello RazorAlliance192 , did u get any solution for this utOfMemoryError: Java heap space ?